# Use a TextBox to filter a Listbox Script problem

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

I have a UserForm intarface with a listbox with 20 column and a text box, I need tanta when I type in a text box the word is searched in every column and row and the result of row are displayed in listbox1. I have put this code but when I add a second column script it doesn’t work yet.

In a nutshell:
I need to find the result of a keyword put in the text box1 in 20 column and put the result in a listbox1

Many thanks

```
    Private Sub Textbox1_Change()

            Dim o As Long
            Dim arrList As Variant

            Me.ListBox1.Clear
If Worksheets(“Sheet1”).Range("A" & Worksheets(“Sheet1”). Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row > 1 And Trim(Me.TextBox1.Value) <> vbNullString Then arrList = Worksheets(“Sheet1”). Range("A1:A" & Worksheets(“Sheet1”).Range("A" & Worksheets(“Sheet1”).Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value2

If Worksheets(“Sheet1”).Range("B" & Worksheets(“Sheet1”). Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row > 1 And Trim(Me.TextBox1.Value) <> vbNullString Then arrList = Worksheets(“Sheet1”). Range("B1:" & Worksheets(“Sheet1”).Range("A" & Worksheets(“Sheet1”).Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value2

For o = LBound(arrList) To UBound(arrList)
If InStr(1, arrList(o, 1), Trim(Me.TextBox1.Value), vbTextCompare) Then
 Me.ListBox1.AddItem arrList(o, 1)
                    End If
                Next o
            End If
            If Me.ListBox1.ListCount = 1 Then Me.ListBox1.Selected(0) = True

        End Sub
```

Comment: Sounds like you need another loop through the columns?

Comment: Yes but if put two “if” it isn’t correct

Comment: What I mean is that you are looking at `arrList(i, 1)` but presumably `arrList` has 20 columns so you need to nest a For loop inside the `o` loop.

Comment: No this is only a typing error, I can’t put another loop for the other column, I have change the text thanks

Comment: I found these mistakes:  Range("B1:"  should be  Range("B1:B" , and the last  End If  is not accounted for i.e. it has to be deleted.